# How to extract td HTML tags with Python BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap a [webpage](http://bgp.he.net/AS2#_prefixes) and extract prefixes and their names out of it. however, for some of the tags, I cannot extract them and my guess is that there are invisible tags. Here is my python code:

```
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open('http://bgp.he.net/AS23028#_prefixes')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup_1 = soup.find("table", id = "table_prefixes4")
soup_2 = soup_1.findAll("td")
print soup_2
```

Does anybody have any idea how to get the name after  tags? Here is the html content of the page:

```
<div class="flag alignright floatright"><img alt="United States" src="/images/flags/us.gif?1282328089" title="United States"/></div>
</td>, <td class="nowrap">
<a href="/net/209.176.111.0/24">209.176.111.0/24</a>
</td>, <td>Savvis
```

and I want to extract prefix "209.176.111.0/24" and "Savvis" from the HTML

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'invisible' tag. Either the tag is there or it is not. If you don't see the tag, there are three possible causes: The HTML is malformed and the parser had to drop some tags to make it all work again, the server varies the content served based on the exact request data (URL, parameters, cookies, other HTTP headers), or JavaScript altered the HTML tree structure after loading into your browser.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what I mean is that I can see the tag when I suspect the page, but I cannot grab it when I try to parse it with beautifulsoup

Comment: In this case, the names are *right there in the source*; every second `td` has got the names.

Comment: How are you trying to grab them then? I can see them just fine when using BeautifulSoup 4 and either lxml or `html.parser` (the fallback if lxml is not installed).

Comment: `soup.select('table#table_prefixes4 tr')[1].get_text(' - ', strip=True)` produces `u'38.229.0.0/16 - PSINet, Inc.'` for me.

Comment: Yes that answers my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is *right there*; nothing is missing in the page. The HTML doesn't appear to be broken (enough) for tags to be lost, nor is there any JavaScript altering the page in the browser:

```
for row in soup.select('table#table_prefixes4 tr'):
    print row.get_text(' - ', strip=True)
```

prints the whole table including the headers.

To get just the cells:

```
for row in soup.select('table#table_prefixes4 tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if not cells:
        continue
    print [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in cells]
```

The latter produces:

```
>>> for row in soup.select('table#table_prefixes4 tr'):
...     cells = row.find_all('td')
...     if not cells:
...         continue
...     print [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in cells]
... 
[u'38.229.0.0/16', u'PSINet, Inc.']
[u'38.229.0.0/19', u'PSINet, Inc.']
[u'38.229.32.0/19', u'PSINet, Inc.']
[u'38.229.64.0/19', u'PSINet, Inc.']
[u'38.229.128.0/17', u'PSINet, Inc.']
[u'38.229.252.0/22', u'PSINet, Inc.']
[u'68.22.187.0/24', u'AS23028.NET']
[u'192.138.226.0/24', u'Computer Systems Consulting Services']
[u'203.28.18.0/24', u'Information Technology Services']
[u'204.74.64.0/24', u'SAUNET']
[u'209.176.111.0/24', u'Savvis']
[u'216.90.108.0/24', u'Savvis']
```